# aggregate data for uniquely tagged values in a list in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate

I was wondering if somebody could help.

I'm trying to aggregate some data in a list based on id values, I have a listBuffer which is updated from a foreach function. My output means I have an id number and a value, because the foreach applies a function to each id often more than once, the list I end up with looks something like the following:

```
ListBuffer(3106;0, 3106;3, 3108;2, 3108;0, 3110;1, 3110;2, 3113;0, 3113;2, 3113;0)
```

What I want to do is apply a simple function to aggregate this data, so I am left with

```
List(3106;3 ,3108;2, 3110;3, 3113;2)
```

I thought this could be done with foldLeft or groupBy, however I'm not sure how to get it to recognise id values and normal values.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't group key-value pairs this way. In scala you have tuples which are written as

`val pair: (Int, Int) = (3106,3)`, where

```
pair._1 == 3106
pair._2 == 3
```

are true statements.

So you have:

```
  val l = ListBuffer((3106,0), (3106,3), (3108,2), (3108,0), (3110,1), (3110,2), (3113,0), (3113,2), (3113,0))

  val result = l.groupBy(x => x._1).map(x => (x._1, x._2.map(_._2))).map(x => (x._1, x._2.sum)).toList

  println(result)
```

will give you

```
List((3106,3), (3108,2), (3110,3), (3113,2))
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I've updated my function to output tuples into the buffer and this works a treat.

Many thanks!